# ng-click not working in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

NG-click not firing in ng -repeat. I want to use ngclick to display only the specific element details.

```
<body ng-app="mainApp" >
     <div ng-app = "mainApp" class="container" ng-controller="TableFilterController">
    <table ng-app = "mainApp" class ="table table-hover"> 
    <tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Role</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="p in details "><td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td><td><a  ng-click="clickMe()">{{p.name}}</a></td><td>{{p.age}}</td><td>{{p.mass}}</td></tr>
    </table>

        </div>
    </body>
```

js:

```
var mainApp= angular.module("mainApp", []);

    mainApp.controller('TableFilterController', function($scope) {
    $scope.clickMe = function(){
       alert("hey");
    }
```

Comment: remove `ng-app` on other elements than body

Comment: Removing redundant `ng-app` doesn't fix it. Angular simply ignores the redundant `ng-app` occurrences. There's nothing wrong with the code you've shared so far. I tried copying your code into a plunker and [it works perfectly fine](https://plnkr.co/edit/blQcxM14aWegLufYSZ8o). Please share any error messages in the browser console and any other relevant code.

Comment: Tried doing that too.Still having the same problem

Comment: If you open the plunker above, you'll see it works exactly as intended and I havn't changed anything apart from adding `$scope.details` so there was some data to show. We need more information in order to help you further. What you've shared so far works just fine.

Comment: yes, I checked it.worked fine in plunker. But tried it in chrome i am still facing that

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen here is the full code  https://plnkr.co/edit/FluJQRlTkdsNfv1NLDhW

Comment: @JayanthyMohit Your plunker seems to be working perfectly fine after you fixed the `<a>`-tag not wrapping `{{p.name}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be different-2 scenarios:
1. Remove Duplicate ng-app.

2.Use This Once,this will test if controller is calling onload or not

```
   mainApp.controller('TableFilterController', function($scope) {
   alert("its Calling");
 $scope.clickMe = function(){
       alert("hey");
    }
```

3. Check you have mentioned controller name in routing.
   4.Check your file's code is loading in browser.

Check these points on first priority otherwise try to create plunker so that everyone can look into your code.

Comment: <a ng-click="clickMe()">{{p.name}}</a>

Comment: Was this issues ? because after correcting this, Everything seems working fine

Comment: yes got that. Can we access specific data from the ng-click .I mean when I  press the element  I need to fetch the details of that particular element .?

Comment: Yes , pass p in clickme(p) and get it in controller

Comment: yes,pass p in your function i.e ng-click="clickMe(p)" and get it in controller i.e $scope.clickMe() = function(data){ console.log(data)}

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove `ng-app` in table tag, `ng-app` for application, only once you can use it.
Also no need for a tag for click event because a tag has `href` attribute.
Use `button` tag or any other tag rather than a `tag`.

Comment: yes tried removing ng-app in table tag .still the same. Even tried the button dont know why ng-click isnt being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code. There were some issues in your code.

**The isseus in the code were as below**

> 1. Script you provided was incomplete. There were some missing }, ] and )
> 2. Remove ng-app which are not required. It will not create any issues but its not a good practice to include the same ng-app attribute multiple times.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="mainApp">
<div class="container" ng-controller="TableFilterController">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Role</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="p in details "><td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td><td><a ng-click="clickMe()">{{p.name}}</a></td><td>{{p.age}}</td><td>{{p.mass}}</td></tr>
    </table>

</div>
<script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var mainApp= angular.module("mainApp", []);
    mainApp.controller('TableFilterController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.details = [{ "name": "A1", "age": 10, "mass": 20, },
        { "name": "A2", "age": 15, "mass": 30, },
        { "name": "A3", "age": 20, "mass": 40, },
        { "name": "A4", "age": 30, "mass": 60, }]
        $scope.clickMe = function () {
            alert("hey");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The duplicate `ng-app` is not the problem. Angularjs simply ignores redundant occurrences.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen: Yes correct... answer updated. Thanks.